# How to subsample a pandas dataframe respecting the frequency of each class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to subsample a pandas dataframe by taking into account the frequency of each label or category. For instance, consider the class frequency of the following [dataset](https://pastebin.com/TqqZ3Q85):

```
Class              freq
Iris-setosa        50
Iris-versicolor    50
Iris-virginica     50
```

[image: frequency for each class]

How can I randomly take the 50% of instances for each class, in order to reduce my dataset?. I all ready know that I can do:

```
df['class'].sample(frac=0.5)
```

or:

```
df.take(np.random.permutation(len(df))[:5])
```

However, this is not respecting the class frequency of the dataset. Any idea of how to get:

```
Class              freq
Iris-setosa        25
Iris-versicolor    25
Iris-virginica     25
```

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Comment: Thanks for the help @sergzach, the issue is that with sample I am not getting the same proportion for each class... I updated my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` on the 'Class' column, then use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df.groupby('Class').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, frac=0.5).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The above solution will get rid of your existing index values.  If you want to maintain your original index values, use `reset_index(level='Class', drop=True)`.

Showing this on some example data:

```
# Setup fake data.
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Class': list('AAAABBBBCC'),
    'Value1': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
    'Value2': np.random.random(10)})
```

Which gives the following initial DataFrame:

```
  Class  Value1    Value2
0     A       0  0.018571
1     A       2  0.182415
2     A       7  0.332961
3     A       3  0.150202
4     B       8  0.810506
5     B       7  0.716278
6     B       0  0.191527
7     B       6  0.097532
8     C       8  0.374224
9     C       6  0.215276
```

Then using the solutions above:

```
# Creating a new index.
df.groupby('Class').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, frac=0.5).reset_index(drop=True)

  Class  Value1    Value2
0     A       0  0.018571
1     A       7  0.332961
2     B       0  0.191527
3     B       6  0.097532
4     C       6  0.215276


# Maintaining the existing index.
df.groupby('Class').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample, frac=0.5).reset_index(level='Class', drop=True)

  Class  Value1    Value2
0     A       0  0.018571
2     A       7  0.332961
6     B       0  0.191527
7     B       6  0.097532
9     C       6  0.215276
```

Comment: Thanks for the help root. What about if I just want to sub sample %50 of one column and leave the other columns?

Comment: Also, does the return value of `sample` always is random?.. I checked the docs... However, I just want to be sure...

Comment: @Anon: The return value of `sample` will be random.  In my example code above I set a random seed with `np.random.seed([3, 1415])` in order to make the results reproducible.  The random seed essentially forces the same random behavior each time, which is useful for testing, but you probably want to remove the `np.random.seed([3, 1415])` line in your actual code.

Comment: @Anon: Not sure what you mean by "sub sample %50 of one column and leave the other columns".  All columns in a DataFrame need to have the same length, so something like that wouldn't be a valid DataFrame.  Did you maybe mean subsample one *'Class'* value, and leave the others as is?

Comment: If it's only one class, you can use `drop` on a subsample of the dataframe filtered to just the class you want remove, i.e. `df.drop(df[df['Class'] == 'A'].sample(frac=0.5).index)`.  In his case, the number you pass to `frac` is the fraction you want to drop, not keep.